# Assignment 2 - How to get max stars

Tags: atelier-rorona

What exactly do I need to do in order to get maximum stars on Assignment 2 (Creating Explosives)?

I have read online, to only make Barrels...without worryin about quality. I have done that and do not get enough stars at the end.

Does anybody know the exact steps needed to get max stars for this assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you don't need max stars to pass a Kingdom Assignment, you do need a minimum of 3 small stars out of 10 stars to pass an assignment (3-5 starts equal 1 Big Star).

the stars relate to the ending from the total amount of stars you obtain

- **True Ending:**     Assignment Stars 94+, Popularity 80+
- **Good Ending:**     Assignment Stars <94, Popularity 80+
- **Normal Ending:**   Assignment Stars 94+, Popularity <80
- **Bad Ending:**  Assignment Stars <94, Popularity <80

as for getting 10 stars for Assignment 2, the Rating for the assignment is determined by  Types of Items and Item Quality but mainly it's Quality.

most walkthroughs will suggest using Barrels because they are cheap to make as the recipe is

- [Liquids] x2
- Eiche x2
- Supplement x1

this makes it easier to make a high quality barrel as supplement is made from just any item and Liquids are easy to get/make